# Как правильно обработать ответ в angular через $resource?

Tags: angularjs

Приложение работает на angular. В контроллере я хочу получить переменную

```
$scope.isPartisipant = service.isPartisipant(id);
```

В сервисе есть метод,

```
function isParticipant(id) {
        return $resource('/isParticipant', {"id": id}).get({});
    }
```

который должен вернуть true или false

Сервер обрабатывает запрос корректно и по адресу /isParticipant?id=2345 отдает true или false

Как мне в js получить это значение? Не могу понять, как обработать ответ. Может функцию isParticipant стоит реализовать по-другому?

Сейчас переменная `isParticipant = Resource` - объект, но если возвращать значение объектом в JSON, то оно появляется в переменной.

Comment: _isParticipant_ не может быть _undefined_ так как функции класса `$resourse` возвращают объект

Comment: @Grundy вы правы, я ошибся

Comment: как вы хотите использовать эту переменную? Обычно при работе в resource - значение сразу пробрасывается во вью. Кроме этого у функций есть параметры succesCallback,errorCallback, и кроме этого у  объекта resource есть свойство $promise

Comment: @Grundy Эта переменная должна влиять на отображение html-элемента.

Comment: скорее всего можно ее сразу использовать в директивах типа: ng-show/ng-if - когда придет ответ - view Должно правильно перерисоваться

Comment: хотя да, с примитивными данными это не сработает :)

Comment: @Grundy вот собственно и проблема, как мне получить примитивное значение? может запрос по-другому строить или же ответ как-то обработать? А эту переменную как раз использую в директиве сразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа `ng-resource` основана на том, что при вызове функции, например `$resource('/isParticipant', {"id": id}).get({})` создается объект класса `Resource`, который используется как заглушка, до получения ответа от сервера. При получении ответа - в текущий объект заглушку добавляются все свойства полученного объекта.
Как можно заметить, такая схема не будет работать с примитивными значениями.

Поэтому в качестве решения можно делать следующее:

1. возвращать объект, с полем, которое можно сразу использовать во view
2. не использовать `ngResource`, а использовать `$http` напрямую. Например так:

   ```
   $http.get('/isParticipant', {'params':{"id": id}}).then(function(response){
       $scope.isPartisipant = response.data;
   });
   ```

**[Пример можно увидеть на Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmWwAizCOP0Un9fph5QV?p=preview)**